# Wearing clothes that promote ones business on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, covid19-pandemic

With many shuls (at least in the UK) still requiring their congregants to wear masks, I have noticed that there have been many people who as part of their business now wear [personalised masks](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=face%20masks%20with%20your%20business%20logo%20on&sxsrf=ALeKk00geL6tyhPhzJqPO6W1_IF-sJNfRA:1622188395312&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCnr7Y8uvwAhWpBGMBHViCDWkQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1536&bih=775), which to a certain extent have either now been integrated into their company's work outfit or merely act as another form of self promotion.

Would a person be allowed to wear such a mask, or any clothes for that matter, that promote one's business on Shabbos. In the case of the masks, on the one hand they are complying with the shul's requirement to adhere to the current nationwide advice, and it's 'just' a mask, but at the same time they are perhaps 'advertising' on Shabbos.

Comment: What's the problem with [passive] 'advertising' on Shabbos?

Comment: I wonder if people are allowed to read such advertisements on shabbos, and if not it would be causing them to stumble.

Comment: How would this be different from promoting someone else's business? @robev I see Red-Sox-themed Kippot often enough

Comment: @DoubleAA And I see Judaica-store-themed tallis bags, and publishing-company-themed siddurim.

Comment: Ever saw a Mishpacha, Ami, etc they're filled with Ads...

Comment: Nonetheless, being that it fulfills the purpose of "safety" the issur so to speak of מ״חפצך is somewhat of a גרמה which as the מ״ג׳ שבת is מתור, Pashtus לכתחלה as תוס׳ in כתובות ג understands מתור - משמע לכתחלה

Comment: @Alex Are they promotional siddurim or are they siddurim that happen to bear the imprint of the publisher? Completely different concepts.